# ¿Como creo un bucle infnito para que pare cuando yo diga?

Tags: java

La idea es crear un bucle que vaya realizando una operacion y pare cuando yo diga. Por ejemplo presionando una tecla.
Este es el ejercicio. 
Crearemos un programa llamado aleatorio que generará números aleatorios según le pasemos por parámetros de entrada, por ejemplo entre 10 y 500. Mostrará por salida estándar línea a línea cada uno de los números generados hasta que lo cerremos. Compilaremos y crearemos el ejecutable aleatorios.jar

Esto es el codigo que he hecho me queda el bucle que no se que poner de condicion

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("introduce el primer numero");
        int num1 = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("introduce el segundo numero");
        int num2 = entrada.nextInt();
        double resultado = 0;
        while ( )) {
            if (num1 > num2) {
                resultado = Math.random() * (num1 - num2) + num2;
            } else {
                resultado = Math.random() * (num2 - num1) + num1;
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: Mira este hilo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105122/loop-in-java-until-the-users-pushes-enter , te va a ayudar

Comment: Buenas @chikebox, no es duplicado si es de SO ingles. Se considera duplicado cuando ya existe aquí, en español. Es mas, algo muy común es traducir preguntas y respuestas de SO ingles (nombrando y dando el merito al autor original), te animo a responderla :)

Comment: Si y no porque no se en que parte meto mi codigo para probarlo

Comment: aah vale, pues le quito el posible duplicado :)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes dentro del bucle usar `String userInput = entrada.next();` para capturar la tecla con la que quieras parar el bucle. También nos ayudaremos de una variable `boolean`.

**Ejemplo:**

```
 boolean keepWaiting  = true;

 while (keepWaiting) {
     String userInput = entrada.next();

     if (num1 > num2) {
         resultado = Math.random() * (num1 - num2) + num2;
     } else {
         resultado = Math.random() * (num2 - num1) + num1;
     }

     if("0".equals(userInput)) {   
         keepWaiting = false;
     }  
 }
```

Espero que pueda servirte.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo con este hilo: [Como hacer algo hasta que el usuario presione intro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105122/loop-in-java-until-the-users-pushes-enter), tu código podría quedar así:

EDIT:
He editado el código ya que puede que no te haga falta todo lo que tiene el ejemplo que te he puesto en el enlace, sí que terminaba el proceso, de hecho te he puesto el resultado por pantalla para que se vea claramente que sí que termina el proceso:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("introduce el primer numero");
    int num1 = entrada.nextInt();
    System.out.println("introduce el segundo numero");
    int num2 = entrada.nextInt();
    double resultado = 0;
    boolean blankLine = true;
    while (System.in.available() == 0) {
              // Tu código
              if (num1 > num2) {
                   resultado = Math.random() * (num1 - num2) + num2;
              } else {
                   resultado = Math.random() * (num2 - num1) + num1;
         }
    }
    System.out.println(resultado);
}
```

Comment: no rula, el bucle no para por mas teclas que le de y mas veces que le de intro

Comment: a ver, voy a editar el código, que he dado por hecho que iba a funcionar, voy a mirarlo y edito la respuesta

Answer (score -1):

Para el bucle infinito puedes utilizar `while(ExpresiónBooleana)` y para salir del bucle necesitas utilizar la sentencia `break;`

La sentencia while evaluará la expresión booleana entre paréntesis, y continuará ejecutando la(s) sentencia(s) dentro de las llaves enroscadas siempre y cuando la expresión sea verdadera.

Luego puedes crear una salida por pantalla que pregunte si deseas salir del bucle y con un condicional if seguir o salir del bucle dependiendo del valor.

Comment: Ya esa es la teoria del while y yo tb me lase ahora el problema es hacer que pare al pulsar una tecla me da igual enter 0 o cualquiera o un clic de raton jaja que poner al while si para es true break es obvio pero como evaluas el parar es  la cosa